# Nordic nRF51822 + Nordic IoT SDK

Tags: c, arm, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf51, system-on-chip

Nordic released an [IoT SDK](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-Smart-Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF51-IoT-SDK) for some platforms (including the nordic nRF51822 BLE SoC) that allows developers to directly connect BLE devices to the internet (with IPv6 over BLE) using a BLE enabled computer or router as a gateway (the Raspberry Pi with the BlueZ stack is recommended).

Thing is I've had no luck getting ANY of the examples they provide in the SDK to compile. Even making my own makefile by hand is leading me nowhere, firstly because Nordic completely alters the folder structure in this SDK in relation to the others, and also because I always get the weirdest compilation errors even after solving all dependencies.

Does anyone have an environment set up with this SDK or can provide some help in setting one up?

Note: Yes, I've asked this question in the Nordic Semi Dev zone, but I think it will get more visibility here (and from a different demographic, aka. makefile gurus, since this is not a embedded problem, since what's failing is the X-Compilation process).

Answer (score 0):

I made it compile on Windows today. What errors are you getting?

The IoT softdevice was compiled with ARM-GCC 4.7 2013q1. So you need this version to compile yourself.